# SFML window does not update unless a key/mouse is pressed

Tags: c++11, window, sfml

I am using SMFL 2.3.2

My code draws a square, and adds a Rotate(int degrees) function which rotates the square upon each game loop execution.

The problem is that the animation happens only if I hover my mouse non-stop over the window or if I hold down a certain key.

I presume that this is happening due to some video card settings/drivers since it works properly on the PC which I use at work.

My laptop runs an INTEL HD Graphics 4000 card.

Below is the code I used:

```
#include "SFML\Graphics.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    //initialize window object
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML");

    sf::CircleShape polygon(50,4);
    polygon.rotate(45);
    polygon.move(sf::Vector2f(200,200));

    //as long as we haven't closed the window
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;

        //check for events
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {           
            switch (event.type)
            {           

            case sf::Event::Closed:       //check for CLOSED event
                window.close();
                break;              

            }
            polygon.rotate(0.4);
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(polygon);
        window.display();
    }
}
```

Any advises are warmly welcomed!

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with the code above is that it will rotate the polygon only when there's an event on the event queue.

So, when you hover your mouse above window, there's a mouseover event that's available for and `window.pollEvent(event)` returns true and `polygon.rotate(0.4)` is called.

refer [SFML doc](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Window.php#a338e996585faf82e93069858e3b531b7) for details

If you move the `polygon.rotate(0.4)` out of the `while (window.pollEvent(event))`, I guess your desired behavior will be obtained.

```
// code snip from above
while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event event;

    //check for events
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {           
        switch (event.type)
        {           

        case sf::Event::Closed:       //check for CLOSED event
            window.close();
            break;              

        }
        // polygon.rotate(0.4);  Moved this out of the while loop
    }

    polygon.rotate(0.4);   // rotate in each game loop

    window.clear();
    window.draw(polygon);
    window.display();
}
```

Hope this helps!